# modemmanager conflicts with arduino

Tags: usb, arduino

I have a problem with modemmanager.
I have a huawei e3372h usb stick lte and the arduino IDE.
When I want to upload a code to arduino ,I get an error (---> port is busy).
But when I write in terminal this command:  sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove modemmanager 
,then I have no more problems as about arduino IDE.
But when I want to have internet connection from Huawei E3372H usb stick ,I can't ,because I maybe have to install modemmanager.
So,I have this conflict.
What should I do to solve this problem/conflict ???

~ Ubuntu 18.04
~ Arduino IDE 1.8

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try blacklisting the Arduino for modemmanager via udev rules:

- As root, create a new file e.g. `arduino-boards.rules` in /etc/udev/rules.d
- Still as root, add the following line to the new file:

`ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"`

- Save the file, and then run:

`sudo udevadm control --reload-rules`

`sudo udevadm trigger`

Important: The "idVendor" number is valid only for Arduino boards. You can do the same for any other boards. The device usually advertises its vendor ID on connection in the syslog which you can check e.g. via `dmesg`.

Comment: Hello again!!!  I have followed your commands step by step ,but I have still the same problem.The only solution is to remove modemmanager ,but then I will have problem with huawei e3372h usb stick.

Comment: Have you made sure you entered the correct vendor ID? If it is not a genuine Arduino/Genuino board, the ID will be different. You can find it out with `udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0 |grep ID_VENDOR_ID`, if your board connects to /dev/ttyACM0.

Comment: This is the command I have inside arduino_boards.rules(in /etc/udev/rules.d)      ->     ATTRS{idVendor}=="2a03", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"                     ,when I wrote this command:udevadm info --name=/dev/ttyACM0 |grep ID_VENDOR_ID,I got : E: ID_VENDOR_ID=2a03
,but I still have the same error.Thanks!!

Comment: Then I'm afraid I don't know what else could be the problem.

Comment: Anyway thank you for your help!!